# Strapi VK provider auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

For some reason, even after i turned on Vk provider and filled all the ids/clientsecrets, `http://localhost:1337/auth/Vk` page returns `404 Not Found`. Is there some full tutorial on how to make Vk auth provider work?

Comment: The correct URL is `http://localhost:1337/connect/vk`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/blob/master/login-react/doc/vk_setup.md
Found it! But it's still doesn't work for me, at least not yet